# Does Diablo 3 chat support gagging users on a channel (all spammers must be nerfed!)?

Tags: diablo-iii

As a temporary fix to 3007 error, I have the [General] channel on.

This is about as wonderful as poking myself in the eye with a pencil because of the spammers who have already started with their levelling services and gems and and and and...

Is there a in game command to permanently gag them or report them to Bliz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click their name in the chat, a menu comes up where you can block the spammers as well as report them.

Unfortunately, it seems like the spammers are recreating accounts with the same name or similar names, as I have the same person on my ignore list a number of times.